# How to toggle the cursor position between the beginning and the end of the line?

Tags: neovim, cursor-movement, cursor-motions, cursor

In normal mode, I'd like to press a key that behaves like `^` (move the cursor to the first non-blank character of the current line), unless the cursor is already there, in which case it should behave like `$` (move the cursor to the last character of the line).

Comment: What did you try? Also note that `^` and `$` are not symmetrical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the VimScript equivalent to [ax ax's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42806/10604) (using Vim 9's `{}`)

```
command EorBofL {
  const start = col('.')
  normal! ^
  if col('.') isnot# start
    normal! $
  endif
}
nnoremap <silent> KEY :EorBofL<enter>
```

Additionally, if you will never write `:EorBofL` yourself, might as well make it an (autoload) function instead of a command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although it's not clear to me what's the advantage of an autoload function vs a command. (The n there is normal mode, being [KEY] the actual key to bind).

Comment: Personally i would use autoload here. Commands i generally reserve for “cant be done otherwise” or “i would type this, not map it” @axax

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find a way to do it, I wrote a function (in nvim). Never done any scripting in vim, so chances are something is slight off or completely wrong, but it seems to work.

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('EorBofL', function()
  local init_col = vim.fn.col('.')
  vim.cmd('norm! ^')
  local current_col = vim.fn.col('.')
  if init_col == current_col then
    vim.cmd('norm! $')
  end
end, {})
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', [KEY], ':EorBofL<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```